# wordpress create user after form submit with ajax call

Tags: ajax, wordpress, http-status-code-404

i  am submitting on form in my wordpress template which goes to remote website now i want to create user with that from fields.but if the form submitted normally then user will not created and form will be redirect to remote url so i use ajax call for this,how ever the user is created but after success function it shows 404 file not found and form does not get submitted.here are the codes first one is ajax request from form fields

```
<script language ="javascript" type = "text/javascript" >

$na= jQuery.noConflict();
$na(document).ready(function(){ 

             $na('#infuse').click(function(){
        alert('start');
                     var name=$na('#inf_field_FirstName').val();
                     var password=$na('#inf_field_Password').val();
                     var email = $na('#inf_field_Email').val();


             $na.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: '<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/user_create.php',
                         data: 'name='+name+'&email='+email+'&password='+password,
                         cache: false,


                         success: function(){

                                                                               jQuery("#inform").submit();  
                                           }
                                      });


                }); 
 });

</script>
```

here is code in user.php file

```
<?php require('./../../../wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
 <?php 

 $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
 $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
 $password=$_REQUEST['password'];
 wp_create_user( $name, $password, $email ); 

 ?>
```

how ever user created in admin that means ajax works but after that it shows 404 error in console and the form submit process stops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
<?php require('./../../../wp-load.php'); ?>
```

in place of

```
<?php require('./../../../wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php require('../../../wp-load.php'); ?>
```

Instead of:

```
<?php require('./../../../wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
```